# iTunes Connect. Hot to view price history

Tags: app-store-connect

How can we get the infos about the price history for a specific app? (My app)

I just cannot found it in the new interface.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to find the price history of your own app or another organization / individual's app?

Comment: @LodgeApps on my own app